# puntero no inicializado al llamar al constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

Estoy aprendiendo c++ concretamente el estandar 2011 pero me vale cualquier estándar a partir de este, mi problema es que al llamar a coche() dentro del segundo constructor me devuelve el puntero datos sin inicializar.
Como puedo solucionarlo y porque pasa esto?

```
#include <iostream>

class coche
{
private:
    const int num_datos = 3;
    int *datos;

public:
    coche()
    {
        datos = new int[num_datos];
    }
    coche(const coche &nuevo)
    {
        coche(); // aqui esta mi problema
        std::copy(nuevo.datos, nuevo.datos + num_datos, datos);
    }
    ~coche()
    {
        delete[] datos;
    }
};

int main()
{

    coche nuevo_coche;
    coche *copia_coche = new coche(nuevo_coche);
    delete copia_coche;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
coche(const coche &nuevo)
{
    coche(); // aqui esta mi problema
    std::copy(nuevo.datos, nuevo.datos + num_datos, datos);
}
```

Este constructor, tal cual está, es equivalente a este otro:

```
coche(const coche &nuevo)
{
    coche temp = coche(); // aqui esta mi problema
    std::copy(nuevo.datos, nuevo.datos + num_datos, datos);
}
```

Es facil entender ahora el motivo por el que no está incilizado el array `datos`... no estás invocando al constructor por defecto de tu instancia sino que estás creando un objeto diferente.

Lo que tu pretendes hacer, que es invocar a un constructor desde otro, se llama *constructores delegados*, es una característica disponible únicamente a partir de C++11 (estándar del cual estás partiendo) y se implementa así:

```
coche(const coche &nuevo)
  : coche()
{
    std::copy(nuevo.datos, nuevo.datos + num_datos, datos);
}
```

Acostúmbrate a esta sintaxis porque la vas a ver mucho. De hecho el espacio que sigue a los dos puntos se puede usar para inicializar cualquier variable miembro:

```
struct Test
{
  int a;
  std::string b;

  Test()
    : a(10),
      b("hola mundo")
  { }
};

int main()
{
  Test t;
  std::cout << t.a << ' ' << t.b;
}
```